# Generate pdf file using pdfkit and send it to browser in nodejs-expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-pdfkit

I am using pdfkit to generate pdf file and i want to send this pdf file to browser.


But i am getting message  `"TypeError: listener must be a function",`
Also, file is getting generate in my parent directory which i don't want.


**Can anyone explain me how to generate pdf file and send it to browser without storing it at parent directory?**

I am using expressjs here.

#### My code

```
var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');                      
var fs=require('fs');
doc = new PDFDocument();
doc.moveTo(300, 75)
   .lineTo(373, 301)
   .lineTo(181, 161)
   .lineTo(419, 161)
   .lineTo(227, 301)
   .fill('red', 'even-odd');  

var loremIpsum = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam in...';  

doc.y = 320;
doc.fillColor('black')
doc.text(loremIpsum, {
   paragraphGap: 10,
   indent: 20,
   align: 'justify',
   columns: 2
});  

doc.write('out.pdf');
res.download('out.pdf');
```

Comment: I have posted a new question. Need your suggestion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36802587/pdfkit-not-able-to-open-the-pdf-generated

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`doc.write` is the line causing the trouble, which is also a [deprecated method](http://pdfkit.org/docs/getting_started.html) so don't use it. Instead, use pipe to tell your doc where to stream the information, and remember to close it using `doc.end()`, i.e., like so:

```
doc = new PDFDocument();
doc.pipe( fs.createWriteStream('out.pdf') );

// rest of the code goes here...

doc.end();
```

Note that it's not important that `doc.pipe()` be at the top, it just makes sense to me (you can put it before or after `doc.end()`. It doesn't matter, it'll work just fine). Finally, note that you can use `pipe` to stream directly to a response, there's no need to create the file first and then download it, i.e.:

```
doc.pipe( res )
```

Comment: still file is getting generate in local directory i want to send this file as download to browser.

Comment: @SachinKumbharkar Yes sorry, I forgot to include the fs function in that last example. You still need it, just point it to the HTTP response instead of a local file

Comment: Now i got error message uncaughtException: path must be a string.

Comment: @SachinKumbharkar I'm not sure then. I have had no problem doing it here,are you running the latest version of pdfkit? Anyway, if nothing else, output it to a file using the first method I've shown and then send it to the response. Is that working for you?

Comment: Yes it is working, Can you tell me how to generate pdf using html here?

Comment: I want to generate html table in pdf

Comment: I have posted my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23625988/html-table-in-pdfkit-expressjs-nodejs

Comment: not
      **doc.pipe( fs.createWriteStream(res) )**
but
      **doc.pipe(res)**

Comment: I had to set headers to get it running. Like in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887464/serve-dynamically-generated-pdf-with-remote-images-in-node-js

Answer (score 5):

So Instead try Using

doc.pipe(res);

Comment: i made this as a service on node,
and pass data as parameter and pipe my data on response.
did 
doc.pipe(res)

and on my react side made an axios call - and abosorbed response in arraybuffer and wrote it to a blob.

Comment: Dont forget to end the stream using `doc.end()`

Comment: Hi , I am stuck in a similar situation with the difference that my code will execute in AWS api gateway. I have written the description in this link , Would be of great help if anyone could take a look and help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57256887/invalid-pdf-structure-error-message-with-nodejs-pdfkit