# How to create dynamic template in fs.createWriteStream?

Tags: node.js

This is my code. I am using pdfkit.
So, instead of sending a text I want to send an HTML template with dynamic data.
Right now I am using doc.text('my text11111').
Can we replace it with a template?

```
var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');

  var doc = new PDFDocument({
        size: 'letter'
    });
    doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('will.pdf'));
    doc.text('my text11111')
    doc.end();
```

Comment: An other post talking about Html in pdfs around node.js and pdfkit subjet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23625988/html-table-in-pdfkit-expressjs-nodejs

Comment: I created an application as per your question.For one time the data is entering into pdf using template.But the second time data is not appending into pdf......

Comment: I have solved that problem @ Syed Ayesha Bebe

Answer (score 0):

To send raw `html` data I suggest you use `pdfkitjs` npm module. It is inspired by `pdfkit`.

It's usage is like this

```
new PDFKit('html', '<h1>Hello</h1>')
```

Please see [the module here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfkitjs)