# How to display a PDF generated with express/pdfkit in browser from api-endpoint

Tags: express, vue.js, pdf, browser, pdfkit

I generate a pdf with with express and pdfkit like:

```js
router.get("/create_pdf", (req, res) => {
  var foo = req.body.foo;
  var bar = req.body.bar;

  // query Postgres with foo and bar to get some custom values
  
  //create pdf
  const doc = new PDFDocument();
  doc.pipe(res);
  doc.fontSize(25).text("Just a header", 100, 80);

  // build some more stuff depending of Postgres query

  doc.end();
})
```

My frontend using vue receives the response

```js
print: function() {
  data = {foo: "foo", bar: "bar"};

  this.axios({
    method: "get",
    url: "get_recipe_as_pdf",
    data: data,
  })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      window.open(response.data);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      //some error
    });
},
```

The console shows `data: "%PDF-1.3↵%����↵7 0 obj↵<...`

window.open(...) opens a blank tab.

I found similar questions but could not find an answer. I probably have some understanding problems, so I'd appreciate a hint. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your express app: `res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');`

In your frontend just open the link "manually" like clicking on an anchor: `<a href="{url to pdf}" target="_blank">click me</a>`

The pdf should open in a new tab if your browser supports that, else it will be downloaded.

Edit: for clarification: `window.open` expects a url as first parameter, not the content of a pdf.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do I understand right, that I have to save the pdf somewhere? My plan was to create it some on-the-fly. And this approach does not work, if I want to send some data via ajax as well. Sorry if the question was not specific enough. I updated the question.

Comment: You do not need to save it on the server side. You can pipe it into the res directly.

Comment: Maybe look at the pdfkit documentation again. If this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58090447/expressjs-and-pdfkit-generate-a-pdf-in-memory-and-send-to-client-for-download) is correct, than you are missing something on your server side.
You client side code definitely won't work, you cannot provide a pdf blob to the window.open method.