# How to read pdf stream in angularjs

Tags: java, angularjs, pdf, inputstream

I got the following PDF stream from a server: [image: PDF STREAM]

How can this stream be read in AngularJS? I tried to open this as a PDF file in a new window by using the following code:

```
.success(function(data) {
   window.open("data:application/pdf," + escape(data));
 });
```

But I'm unable to see the content in opened window.

Comment: why do you transfer the whole file through http and not just open the url of that file? window.open(fileUrl)?

Comment: @MajoB I tried in that way also but in angular I'm getting error like Not allowed to load local resource: failed to load file path..

Comment: See this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628378/angularjs-display-blob-pdf-in-an-angular-app

Comment: Hi I am getting the same kind of response in Angular2, but i can't figure out how to handle such response in angular 2. I am getting an error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at Function.Json.parse" like this.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I achieved this by changing my controller code

```
$http.get('/retrievePDFFiles', {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
       .success(function (data) {
           var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
           var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
           window.open(fileURL);
    });
```

Comment: Ranjit, I was getting blank pdf but adding the "responseType" to the arguments of the $http, it works. I just figured it out, sorry about being late.

Comment: hi I am getting a similar error as Ranjit. On chrome it says: _Failed to load PDF document_ do you know how to solve this?

Comment: I am still getting the same error, even after applying the fix.

Comment: @RanjitSingh see [this ans](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21732039/1509853) And replace $window.open($sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL));

Comment: how to trigger download dialog box instead of opening it in new tab?

Comment: @MPPNBD no idea but i will try and let you know.

Comment: the {responseType: 'arraybuffer'} did the trick for me. I am sending a MemoryStream from .NET Core and making the $http.post from Angularjs like this:  return this.$http.post(url, Indata, {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer'
      })
      .then(res => {
        return res
      });

Answer (score 7):

Pleas have a look on the following code:

On Controller Side -

```
$http.get(baseUrl + apiUrl, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
          .success(function (response) {                  
             var file = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
             var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
             $scope.pdfContent = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
           })
           .error(function () {                        
           });
```

On HTML Side:

```
<div ng-controller="PDFController" class="modal fade" id="pdfModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content" onloadstart="">
        <object data="{{pdfContent}}"  type="application/pdf" style="width:100%; height:1000px" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Also you can go with the Angular **ng-pdfviewer** and view your pdf by using it's js files.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [PDF.JS](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/). This is a client side javascript library that can fetch a pdf stream and render it client side. Angular is unable to read a pdf so this isn't an angular issue.

Answer (score 1):

Java: Get Method

```
BLOB pdfData = getBlob_Data;
response.setContentType(pdfData.getContentType());
response.setHeader(ApplicationLiterals.HEADER_KEY_CONTENT, "attachment;     filename=FileName.pdf");
response.getOutputStream().write(pdfData.getBinaryData());
response.getOutputStream().flush();
```

Comment: Controller :
    function downloadPDF(searchManagerQuery) {
        // calls get method
            $window.open('ServiceURL', '_blank');
        }

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using config.responseType is that the $http service still runs the default responseTransformer and attempts to convert the response to JSON. Also, you are sending the default accept headers. Here is an (untested) alternative:

```
$http.get('/retrievePDFFiles', {
    headers: { Accept: "application/pdf"},  
    transformResponse: function(data) {
        return new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    }}).success(function (data) {
           var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(data);
           window.open(fileURL);
    });
```