# How to mention file name and URL while creating Bolb object from byte[] using angular js

Tags: angularjs, web-services

I am using angular to access a rest API which return `ResponseEntity` of Byte Array like `return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(pdf, headers, HttpStatus.OK);`

My code in front side is as below which I got from [How to read pdf stream in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781927/how-to-read-pdf-stream-in-angularjs])

```
$http.post("http://localhost/app/report/csd/" + projectId, obj, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
                var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                $window.open(fileURL);
            })
            .error(function (err) {
                callback.error(err);
            });
    },

}
```

The file name is being set as header in Rest Api and returned with response as below:

```
 headers.add("Content-Disposition", new StringBuilder("inline; filename=\"").append("report.pdf").append("\"").toString());
```

I want above file name to be set to the Bolb object, and new window URL in address Bar should be the URL of post request.
Hence after  `$window.open(fileURL)` call the address bar should display URL as
http://localhost/app/report/csd/{{project_id}} and generated file should be of name : report.pdf.

currently The URL is coming as `blob:http%3A//localhost%3A8080/88506783-779c-4525-bdc3-329029d23257"` and file with name **88506783-779c-4525-bdc3-329029d23257.pdf**
How can I achieve the above please help!