# AngularJS POST for PDF data always fails

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-web

I'm trying to work around Internet Explorer's URL limits (refer to [this Microsoft support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/208427) for more information) in order to generate a PDF.

I have a base-64 encoded String representing a PDF's byte stream in my client-side JS. For Firefox and Chrome, I show the PDF by prepending the String with `data:application/pdf;base64,` and the browser happily renders the data URI.

For Internet Explorer, I'm trying to send the String back to the servlet in a POST so that it can return the byte stream with content type "application/pdf". Pretty much I'm following the solutions proposed in the following questions, except that I'm passing the actual PDF contents up in the client side request:

- [AngularJS: Display Blob PDF in Angular App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628378/angularjs-display-blob-pdf-in-an-angular-app)
- [How to read pdf stream in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781927/how-to-read-pdf-stream-in-angularjs)

My HTTP POST looks as follows:

```
var pdf; // base-64 encoded string in this variable
$http.post("/convert/pdf", {
    params: {
      base64pdf: pdf
    }
  }, {
    responseType : "arraybuffer"
  }).then( function onSuccess(result) { 
             var file = new Blob([result.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
             window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, "result.pdf");
           },
           function onFailure() { /* log and do failure case stuff */ });
```

My server is running a Java spring-webmvc service. The Convert controller looks as follows:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/convert", produces = "application/pdf")
public class ConvertController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/pdf", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> generatePdf(
        @RequestParam(value="base64pdf", required=true) String base64encodedDataUri,
        HttpServletRequest request) {
      byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(base64encodedDataUri);

      HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));

      String filename = "test.pdf";
      headers.setContentDispositionFormData(filename, filename);
      ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<>(bytes, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
      return response;
    }
    // other methods
}
```

The controller code is based off [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30404899/419705). I don't think there's a problem with it; it tests out fine in unit tests and direct POST requests via the Swagger API interface.

The problem is this. Whenever I trigger this `$http.post` in IE, the result is *always* the error callback, and it's *always* an HTTP 400 error.

I've observed the following:

- Using IE 11's developer tools Network traffic capturing, I can observe the request being made. The request contains the full and correct base-64-encoded string in the params, which is present in the Request Body.
- The Request Header looks like this:

```
Request         POST /convert/pdf HTTP/1.1
Content-Type    application/json;charset=utf-8
Accept          application/json, text/plain, */*
Referer         localhost:8080/
Accept-Language en-US
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
User-Agent      Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host            localhost:8080
Content-Length  5699
DNT             1
Connection      Keep-Alive
Cache-Cont

rol   no-cache
```

- The Response header shows this:

```
Response                     HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server                       Apache-Coyote/1.1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin  *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods POST,GET,OPTIONS,DELETE
Access-Control-Max-Age       3600
Access-Control-Allow-Headers x-requested-with
Content-Type                 application/pdf
Content-Length               98
Date                         Mon, 07 Dec 2015 21:54:32 GMT
Connection                   close
```

- The Response body contains an invalid PDF. Well, technically the developer tools say it can't render it, and when you save it, the PDF that gets saved isn't a valid PDF.
- **EDIT:** I turned up logging in Tomcat8 and observed that Spring is complaining that the "base64pdf" parameter is missing from the request:

```
2015-12-08 02:29:32,514 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] INFO Required String parameter 'base64pdf' is not present
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'base64pdf' is not present
```

---

So I really have two questions:

1. **How am I losing the `base64pdf` parameter?** Is there a max length on parameters or something? I tried both the original displayed in this question, and passing the param in via `data: { base64pdf : pdf }` as suggested by user chenzhenjia below.
2. **How can I get this PDF call to work in IE?** While on the one hand I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong above, but frankly I'm open to "the right answer" for how to get this base-64-encoded string that's on the client side transformed into a PDF. (That is, if this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) and I'm barking up the wrong tree, I'd like to know that too.)

---

I'm using:

- AngularJS 1.4.8
- Spring 4.2.3.RELEASE
- Java 8
- Tomcat 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting this to work by sending the base64pdf String in the request body.

In Java, I created a simple model:

```java
public class PayloadHolder {
  private String payload;
  // getters and setters
}
```

Then I updated my Controller's method signature:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/pdf", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/pdf")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> generatePdf(
        @RequestBody(required = true) PayloadHolder payload,
        HttpServletRequest request)
```

And finally changed the AngularJS request:

```
var pdf; // base-64 encoded string in this variable
var request = {
    payload : pdf
};
var config = {
    headers: { 'Accept': 'application/pdf' },
    responseType : "arrayBuffer"
};

$http.post("/convert/pdf", request, config)
      .then( function onSuccess(result) { 
         var file = new Blob([result.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
         window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, "result.pdf");
       },
       function onFailure() { /* log and do failure case stuff */ });
```

I'm not sure why the POST wouldn't work using params, especially because I couldn't find anything in the documentation that would indicate that it shouldn't. I'll post a follow up question addressing this.

Comment: Accept this as correct answer if this has worked for you, so that others can try this first rather than going through other answers.

Comment: It's not a solution. It's a workaround. It also does not answer *why* my first attempt did not work even though it should (as far as I can tell.) @Bopsi

Answer (score 0):

For $http.post set the content-type as url-form-encoded if you have not specified on server side (spring mvc) other content-type for request, as angular may be sending with other content-type.

Example:

```
$http({
method: "post",
url: URL,
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
data: $.param({base64pdf: pdf})
}).success(function (result){
         var file = new Blob([result.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
         window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, "result.pdf");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the `@RequestMapping` annotation on the method to this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/convert", produces = "application/pdf",method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

---

Alternatively, try the following AngularJS POST:

```
var req = { method: 'POST', url: 'example.com', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/pdf' }, data: { base64pdf: pdf } } 
$http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});
```

Comment: No, adding `produces = "application/pdf"` to the method annotation doesn't make a difference; the request still fails in the same fashion. The behavior is still the same, even when the `produces = ` is set on both the controller and method annotations.

Comment: var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'http://example.com',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'
 },
 data: { base64pdf: pdf }
}

$http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});

Comment: I've copied your second comment into the body of your answer; you should modify your answer directly instead of adding answers as comments. :)

Comment: I was the first time to stackoverflow

Comment: Welcome. I will try your second suggestion now and see how that works out.

Comment: The second suggestion also does not work, and also returns a HTTP 400.