# Angular 6, Open and Download PDF, Issue in Production

Tags: angular, angular6

I am trying to open as well as download PDF in angular web application. the code works fine while development and gets the PDF on angular app. But the same doesn't work while build for production and deployed.

Shows: **"Failed to load PDF document"**

Code as below:

**Service.ts**

```
export(pdfName) {
 const httpOptions = {'responseType': 'arraybuffer' as 'json'};
 return this.http.get<any>(environment.apiBaseUrl + '/download?path='+policyPath,
                           httpOptions);
 }
```

**Component.ts**

```
GetDocument(pdfName:any)
{
 this.service.export(pdfName)
 .subscribe((data) =>
   {
     window.open(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'})),'Popup', 'height=700px,width=900px,scrollbars=1,')
     console.log(data);
   }
   ,(error)=>{
     var res= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(error));
     console.log(res);
     this.alertService.warn("Resource "+res.statusText);
     $('#alertModel').modal('show');
   }
   );
}
```

Again: this code works fine as required in development. Produces issues only when deployed to production.

Comment: Have you looked into the `file-saver` package from `npm`? https://onthecode.co.uk/download-files-with-angular-from-net-core-web-api/

Comment: third party packages do not helps

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: I could not import the method "downloadFile". I have the "saveAs". and I am using that only

Comment: You said no third party packages? Anyway, `downloadFile` is what I import the library as. If you named it `saveAs` in the import, you need to use `saveAs`

Comment: Done so bro, as mentioned works fine in development but not in prod. evironment

Answer (score 0):

In my previous project only this approach worked flawlessly for me

```
getOrderPdf(id: string): Observable<ArrayBuffer> {
  return this.http
    .get(environment.api + "/orders/" + id + "/pdf", {
      responseType: "arraybuffer",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/pdf"
      }
    });
}

printOrder() {
  this.ordersService
    .getOrderPdf(this.order._id)
    .pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe(blob => {
      var newBlob = new Blob([blob], { type: "application/pdf" });

      if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(newBlob);
        return;
      }

      const data = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
      var link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = data;
      link.download = "Order No " + this.order.number + ".pdf";
      link.click();

      setTimeout(() => {
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(data);
      }, 100);
    }, err => {})
}
```

Server side:

```
import * as pdf from "html-pdf";

const template = pug.renderFile(
  path.join(__dirname, "template/print.pug"),
  { order: order }
);

pdf.create(template).toBuffer((err, buffer) => {
  if (err) {
    logger.error(JSON.stringify(err));
    return res.sendStatus(500);
  }
  res.setHeader("Content-type", "application/pdf");
  res.send(buffer);
});
```